# JSON to Typescript Model Unique key

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, react-typescript

```
{
    "title" : "Samsung Galaxy S10",
    "tags" : {
     "android" : true,
     "samsung" : true
    }   
}
```

I am modeling the JSON output with Typescript as follows.

```
export interface PostModel {
    title: string;
    tags:  Tags;
}

export interface Tags {
    android: boolean;
    samsung: boolean;
}
```

How can I make a **unique "key, value"** model when I add tags? Currently I cannot send a key other than android and samsung.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an array of tags?

```
export interface PostModel {
    title: string;
    tags:  Tag[];
}

export interface Tag {
    key: string;
    value: boolean;
}
```

Not sure if typescript has a way to check that all the tags are unique, maybe you could make `tags` a `new Set()` so all values will occur only once

```
let tags = new Set<Tag>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

Also please refer [TypeScript Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```js
export interface UniqueModel {
  [key: string]: any
}

const tags: Tags[] = [];
const obj1: UniqueModel = { tags };
```